Best tool for proving that a (big) first order model is actually the model of some (big) first order theory.
I have to check that a (big: several hundreds axioms) first order logic theory is satisfiable.
There are various authomated provers for first order logic (e.g. Vampire) that could tell me if the theory is satisfiable or not. However, they all fail (they never terminate or run out of resources), due to the size of the theory.
I know of only two model finders for first order logic: Mace4 and Lean. They also fail due to the size.
Let me expand on the charachteristics of the logical theory: it is a foundational ontology. I cannot report it here in full, however it is very similar to any of the foundational ontologies found e.g. in this document (any of the chapters 2,3,4, to be precise).
The ontology signature is made from about 50 unary predicates, about 10 binary predicates, about 5 ternary predicates, and just one quaternary predicate.
A small minority of these are defined predicates which could in principle be removed by replacing them with their definient, the other are all primitives. For the rest equality is used, but no algebraic operations.
The ontology has about 200 axioms, which are of various types.
Many axioms are simple subsumption, disjointedness, and domain/range axioms, i.e. axioms of type (free variables are universally quantified):
$$A(x) \Rightarrow B(x)$$
$$B(x) \Rightarrow \neg C(x)$$
$$E(x,y,z) \Rightarrow F(x) \land G(y) \land H(z)$$
respectively, where $A$ to $H$ are appropriate predicate symbols.
Equality is used and there are some functionality declarations e.g.:
$$\phi(x,y) \Rightarrow x = y$$
where $\phi$ is a conjunction of unary and binary predicates.
There are also more complex axioms, one type of axioms that are especially problematic are non-emptiness of classes and existential rules, i.e.
$$\exists x A(x)$$
$$\phi(\bf{x},\bf{y}) \Rightarrow \exists \bf{z} (\psi(\bf{z}, \bf{y}))$$
where $A$ is an appropriate predicate, and $\phi$ and $\psi$ are conjunctions of atomic predicates and the variables in bold stand for (short) lists of variables. There are about >30 existential rules.
There are also some axioms in which a disjunction is present in the consequent of an entailment
There is also a small number of most complex axioms, which have multiple nested quantifiers: consider e.g. the definition of mereological sum from Wikipedia
$$U(x,y) \Rightarrow \exists z \forall v (O(v,z) \Leftarrow \Rightarrow (O(v,x) \land O(v,y)))$$
As said, understandably, the tools I know fail to find a model.
Nevertheless, I think I can produce an explicit model for the theory. Lets assume that we specify the model as a list of constants, followed by a list of true atomic statements, with the convention that non-explicitely stated facts are false. Then the model contains about 25 constants and about 200 statements. It would look like this:
$constants$ (all different): $c1, c2, ..., c25$
$relations: A(c1), A(c2), B(c1), ..., P(c1, c4, c16), ..., Z(c22,c23,c24,c35)$
Now, due to the size of the model and of the number of axioms, I am not actually sure the model is a model, therefore a model checking tool would be quite helpful and would prove that the theory is consistent, or that I was wrong.
The issue is I don't know of any such model checking tool for first order logic, if any exists.
Up to today, the approach I followed consisted in hammering the model into a complete theory containing apprpriate statements and then asking to a prover if all the axioms of the target theory are entailed by the 'theorified' model. E.g., suppose that I want to prove satisfability of the simple theory (with just one binary predicate, $P$)
$$\forall x,y,z . P(x,y) \land P(y,z) \Rightarrow P(x,z)$$
I would like to use a tool that allows me to specify a formal model using the signature of the theory, say:
$constants$ (all different)$: a,b $ 
$relations: P(a,b), P(b,a), P(a,a), P(b,b)$
and that checks if this model is actually a model of the theory. As of now I would 'theorify' the model into the theory:
$$\forall x . (x=a) \lor (x=b)$$
$$a\neq b$$
$$\forall x,y . P(x,y) \Leftrightarrow ((x=a \land y=b)\lor(x=b \land y=a)\lor(x=a \land y=a)\lor(x=b \land y=b))$$
And then ask Vampire if the theorified model entails the transitivity axiom. Not only this is incredible laborious if you have a big model/theory/signature, sometimes Vampire (and any other prover, actually) is not even able to prove an obvious entailment (the entailment is obvious if checking case-by-case, Vampires tries its skolemization resolution algorithm which does not realize this possibility of checking case-by-case).
In summary, my question is:
Are there any model checker tool out there that can help me? Alternatively, is there a simpler way (or even more complex but more performing way) than my current approach to check if a model is actually a model for some first order theory?

I agree with needing more context, more specifically a little bit about what the theory is and where it comes from. I also think this question is a good fit for the Proof Assistants Stack Exchange, but 1) the context issue should be resolved before the question is moved not after (if it is moved at all), 2) I think this question is on topic in both Stack Exchanges.

I flagged the moderators and requested to move it.

Lean is not a "model finder" for first-order theories. Given that your candidate models are finite and not very large, it sounds like a simple checker would be able to verify that you've got a model. This shouldn't be too hard to implement.

Are you looking for a framework that can state and/or prove that your model $\mathfrak{M}$ is actually the model of some first-order theory $\mathcal{T}$? I've already implemented a framework for first-order logic equipped with Leibnize equality in Coq: https://github.com/KiJeong-Lim/Fol-archived/tree/master
You can show $\mathfrak{M} \models \mathcal{T}$ with respect to Tarski's definition of truth in Coq using the framework.

@KijeongLim yes, what you are describing seems to be a solution to my needs, however, looking at the repository you have linked, at its terminology and documentation, I don't understand how I can use it to do what I need. Is it something that will become self-evident if I become familiar with Coq?

@kataph (I had misunderstood your words.) Yes, sure. If you get familiar with Coq, you can use my framework to achieve your goal. An example will be added soon, which will be helpful to you---the example is Coq code that states and proves that there is a model of $\mathsf{CZF}$.

So, for anybody searching for an answer to my question it appears that the situation is as follows:

Are there any model checker tool out there that can help me? No, as of now there are no dedicated model checkers for first-order logic. There are some very early-stage libraries that at some point the future may offer that functionality (e.g. pylogics) or proof assistants that may be exploited to do the same (e.g. the other answer to this question mentions Coq, and two libraries in particular; however, I tried to learn how to use Coq, and it become evident very soon that I would need a lot of time to verify if using these libraries can effectively approach my use case -- this direction may still be useful for people expert with proof assistants).
is there a simpler way (or even more complex but more performing way) than my current approach to check if a model is actually a model for some first order theory? There is another way, which was suggested in the comments: self-developing a program that can check a model against a fol theory. The model-checking problem is computationally treatable, so it is more performing than perverting a theorem prover as per the approach described in the question. It took me a short developing time to have a basic prototype (with a simple brute force approach), and a little bit more to write the full model, so it is not terribly complicated. I published it on this repo. I did not include the big model I needed, only some small examples. It should be simple enough to use by reading the documentation and checking out the tests and the examples. Also it is lightweight with very few dependencies and is written in a widespread programming language. And does exactly what I needed to.


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

There are Coq libraries for formalizing the meta-theory on a first-order language:

A library of Saarland University.
An example is given, which states and proves that there is a model of $\mathsf{ZF}$.
However, this library use the convention of de Bruijn index—i.e., the universal and existential quantifiers do not bind a name.
For example, the formula $$(\forall x) (\forall y) (\forall z) ((R (x , y) \land R (y , z)) \to R (x , z))$$ will be encoded into $ \forall \ \forall \ \forall \ ( (R ( \# 2 , \# 1 ) \land R (\# 1 , \# 0)) \to R (\# 2 , \# 0) ) $.
Thus, it will be hard to describe a formula you want to express.

A library of mine.
There is no example.
Although, Leibniz equality is primitive and the quantifiers bind a name.
For example, the formula $$(\forall x) (\forall y) (\forall z) ((R (x , y) \land R (y , z)) \to R (x , z))$$ can be encoded into $ \forall v_0 \forall v_1 \forall v_2 ( (R ( v_0 , v_1 ) \land R ( v_1 , v_2 )) \to R ( v_0 , v_2 ) ) $.
There are other ways to encode the formula—e.g., $ \forall v_2 \forall v_4 \forall v_5 ( (R ( v_2 , v_4 ) \land R ( v_4 , v_5 )) \to R ( v_2 , v_5 ) ) $.



Note that library 1 is not related to MPI, but Saarland University.

@JoJoModding I corrected it.
